# Как программно соединиться, разъединиться через PPPoE (ADSL)?

Tags: adsl, pppoe, c#

Люди, помогите программно подключиться (на C# желательно, но можно и не на нем) к интернету по PPPoE (ADSL у меня), шарил по нэту везде либо на мсдн, где нет примеров, либо dotras.codeplex.com (там VPN или только создание подключения - так и не понял), дайте, пожалуйста хоть какой-нибудь работающий пример, замучался уже...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На C# в Windows вот так в общем:

соединение:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "название_соединения логин пароль");
```

разъединение:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "название_соединения /DISCONNECT");
```

Answer (score 1):

DotRas - это лучшее, что есть для C# для работы с PPPoE. Ссылки по теме:

- [PPPOE Dialer](http://dotras.codeplex.com/discussions/208875) с форума DotRAS
- [Starting a RAS Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378082(v=vs.85).aspx) с MSDN (WinCE)
- [Введение в RAS](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/net/rasstat.xml) c RSDN

Answer (score 1):

Набрать с DotRas не проблема. Набирает. Вот только почему-то после таймаута разрывает соединение...

Пример того как набрать:

```
RasPhoneBook CurrentUserPhoneBook;
RasDialer Dialer = new RasDialer();
    Init()
            {
             CurrentUserPhoneBook = new RasPhoneBook();

                CurrentUserPhoneBook.Open(true);
                foreach (RasEntry re in CurrentUserPhoneBook.Entries)
                {
                    if (re.Device.DeviceType.Equals(RasDeviceType.PPPoE,
                                                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //сохрани в лист например все пппое записи

                        myPPPoEConnectionList.Add(re);
                    }
                }
        }
           private void Dial(RasEntry re)
                {
                    // This button will be used to dial the connection.
                    this.Dialer.EntryName = re.Name;
                    this.Dialer.PhoneBookPath = CurrentUserPhoneBook.Path;
                    this.Dialer.Timeout = 20000;
                    this.Dialer.AllowUseStoredCredentials = true;

                    try
                    {
                        // NOTE: The entry MUST be in the phone book before the connection can be dialed.
                        // Begin dialing the connection; this will raise events from the dialer instance.
                        this.pppoeConnectionHandle = this.Dialer.DialAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //LogWriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону RAS.

Вот, например, какое-то обсуждение: [NET RAS/RASDIAL Structures](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/347785-vb-net-ras-rasdial-structures)

Comment: А это подойдет для моего соединения WAN Miniport (PPPOE)? А то в этом RAS везде Dial-up соединение описывается.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой проблемой. Пришлось написать утилиту контроля. Подходит для любого языка. При запуске с параметрами передает в окно, с указанным handle состояние подключения (SendMessage(Hwnd,WM_MBUTTONDOWN,MK_MBUTTON,sValue). А через буфер обмена и IP адрес. Могу поделиться - multisoft@rambler.ru