# Как через c# закрыть и заново подключить PPPoe соединение на Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, сетевое-программирование, pppoe

Как через c# закрыть и заново подключить PPPoe соединение на Windows 7 ?

Comment: Через WinAPI или WMI? Если WMI, то можно обратиться к классу Win32_NetworkAdapter, если память не изменяет NetConnectionId адаптера должен быть "Local Area Connection", ну и метод для отключения - Disable.

Comment: В дополнение к вопросу "как подключить" - [получить список VPN-подключений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610379/get-windows-vpn-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7813/Как-программно-соединиться-разъединиться-через-pppoe-adsl?rq=1